# Error al enviar/recibir un String entre maestro y esclavo por PVM

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, shell

Estoy haciendo una práctica que consiste en una comunicación mediante PVM en Ubuntu con lenguaje C entre un maestro y un esclavo que hacen ciertas operaciones con un fichero. Después de hacer dichas operaciones (me funcionan bien), tengo que hacer que el maestro mande al esclavo el nombre del fichero que tiene que manejar.

Fragmento del código del maestro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pvm3.h>

#define MAX 256
#define NOMFICH "BreastTissueTrain.csv"

int main(){
    /*
       ...
    */

    //Una vez calculadas las medias y desviaciones pasamos a la parte de PVM
    printf("\n\n---ENVÍO DE DATOS AL PROCESO ESCLAVO---");
    int cc1, cc2, tid;
    int tarea = 1; //1 = mandar nombre fichero, 2 = mandar medias, 3 = mandar desviaciones
    double empaquetarMedia, empaquetarDesviacion;

    printf("\n\nEl id del maestro es: %x\n\n", pvm_mytid());

    cc1 = pvm_spawn("esclavo", NULL, 1, "ubuntu-nodo2", 1, &tid);

    if(cc1==1){
        pvm_initsend(PvmDataDefault); // Inicializar el buffer

        //Mandamos al proceso esclavo el nombre del fichero cuyos datos debe normalizar
        pvm_pkstr(NOMFICH);
        pvm_send(tid, tarea);       
    }else{
        printf("ERROR! No se pudo iniciar el proceso esclavo\n\n");
    }

    pvm_exit();
    exit(0);


}
```

Fragmento del código del esclavo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pvm3.h>

#define MAX 256
#define MIN 64

int main() {
    int ptid, nbytes, msgtag, tid;
    double desempaquetarMedia, desempaquetarDesviacion;
    char *NOMFICH;

    printf("\nIniciando el esclavo...\n");
    printf("Esperando la petición del maestro...\n");

    //ERROR! No pasa de aquí

    //Recibimos el nombre del fichero
    ptid = pvm_parent();
    int bufid = pvm_recv(ptid, -1);
    pvm_bufinfo(bufid, &nbytes, &msgtag, &tid);
    pvm_upkstr(NOMFICH);

    if(msgtag == 1){
        printf("Recibiendo los datos del fichero %s...\n", NOMFICH);
    }else{
        printf("Error en la recepción. Abortando esclavo\n\n");
        pvm_exit();
        exit(0);
    }

    /*
       ...
    */
}
```

Maestro y esclavo están situados en la misma máquina virtual, en la carpeta pvm3/bin/LINUX. El fichero BreastTissueTrain.csv también está en dicha carpeta.

Estoy ejecutando el código mediante la Shell de Ubuntu. Tanto maestro como esclavo no tienen ningún error al compilar, pero a la hora de ejecutar en el maestro solo se muestra por consola hasta el printf con su id y en el esclavo solo los dos primeros printf. No se muestra ningún error, pero tampoco hace nada.

No me funciona el envío del nombre del fichero. Creo que es un problema con el uso de los String, pero no consigo encontrar el error.

Edit: He reservado memoria dinámica para NOMFICH tal y como se muestra en el comentario que he puesto en esta pregunta. Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Buscando un poco en Internet, tu error es que, en tu *esclavo*, no basta con declarar `NOMFICH`; tienes que reservar la memoria necesaria. No he usado nunca `pvm`, así que no te puedo decir mucho mas :-/

Comment: @Trauma He modificado el esclavo como me has dicho y ahora está así esa parte: `char *NOMFICH, *nombreFichero;` `pvm_upkstr(nombreFichero);` `nombreFichero = (char *) malloc(strlen(nombreFichero) + 1);` `strcpy(NOMFICH, nombreFichero);`

Sin embargo, el esclavo sigue quedándose pillado y no muestra el nombre del fichero que ha recibido (`NOMFICH`)